# how can i use wget to download files with scrapy

Tags: python, wget, scrapy

scrapy is not downloading files properly. I have URLs of my items, so I figured I can use wget to download the files.

How can i use wget inside the scrapy `process_item` function? Alternatively, is there another way of download files?

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    #Name download version
    def image_key(self, url):
        image_guid = url.split('/')[-1]
        return 'full/%s' % (image_guid)

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        if item['image_urls']:
            for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            # wget -nH image_ul -P  images/
            yield Request(image_url)
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve exactly and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am downloading images with scrapy but due to some bug in scrapy the gif anmations are downloaded as staic one not animated. so i was thinking i should use wget for downlaoding the images directly rather than writing the images. i will post my pipeline code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will execute wget, you can replace your comment with the following lines

```
import subprocess

    ...

subprocess.call(['wget','-nH', image_url, '-P  images/'])
```

You can read about subprocess.call here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: i get this `wget: illegal option -- ‘-n`

Comment: I edited my answer: I forgot to split arguments, now it should be correct