# scrapy downloadermiddleware to use wget instead of python http middleware

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I have a site which responds 504 to scrapy when crawling on every page.
I tried it with wget and it downloads. I don't have that knowledge of
http protocol so I guess this path of action could be usefull to many
novice scrapers.

What classes, settings and tunings do I have to do in a scrapy project
to use wget instead of the embedded-with-scrapy downloader.

[There is an aswer related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983941/how-can-i-use-wget-to-download-files-with-scrapy)
 but given my scrapy knowledge
I can't see how to conect that in my project.

Comment: share the scrapy logs (maybe on a pastebin) and your `settings.py` file please.

Comment: Look at the `robots.txt` on the website and and see if it is denying specific user agents